# Remove Geometry data that is outside of a polygon

Tags: sql-server, database, gis, ogc

I am creating a SQL Server table that takes data from a OS MasterMap layer if it sits within the SITES_TEST layer.

First I am using STIntersects to get the OS MM data into an ASSETS layer.

```
INSERT INTO ASSETS(GEOMETRY, THEMES) 
    (select b.GEOMETRY, b.THEMES from 
          SITES_TEST a,
          MM_TOPO b
          where a.geometry.STBuffer(1).STIntersects(b.geometry) = 1 AND  (b.THEMES ='Land' or b.THEMES ='Roads Tracks And Paths'))
```

The Blue boundary is my site layer and in the background OS MasterMap.
[image: Blue boundary is my site layer]

After the query above is run in SQL Server it returns the overlapping data as well as the contained data. I get that I could use STContains but then that leaves out data that goes both within and outside the boundary.

[image]

I was hoping I would be able to run an UPDATE on the ASSETS table using STDifference.

```
UPDATE ASSETS(GEOMETRY) 
        (select b.GEOMETRY from 
              SITES_TEST a,
              MM_TOPO b
              where a.geometry.STDifference(b.geometry)=1)
```

But I think I am going about it the wrong way as this is returning a boolean error.

> Invalid operator for data type. Operator equals equal to, type equals
>   geometry.

Summary:
I am trying to remove geometry that is outside of another geometry. The first picture shows a blue polygon, then the SQL script is run which results in the second picture which shows data in red that sits outside the blue boundary polygon from the first picture. I want to remove the data that is now outside the blue polygon.

Comment: I'm having a hard time trying to figure out what you want (even with the pictures), but I will note that `STDifference()` returns a geography data type and you're trying to compare it to a numeric data type in your where clause. That's what the error message is telling you.

Comment: @BenThul Hi Ben I am trying to remove geometry that is outside of  another geometry. The first picture shows a blue polygon, then the sql script is run that results in the second picture which shows data in red that sits outside the blue boundary polygon, I want to remove the data that is now outside the blue polygon.

Comment: Said another way, are you looking for the intersection of two polygons? If so, you should be able to express that intersection with `STIntersects()` and drive the update with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of just asking for geometries that `intersect` the polygon of interest, which returns all of the intersecting geometry (as you found out) you want just the [parts of the geometry that intersect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geometry/stintersection-geometry-data-type?view=sql-server-2017) your polygon of interest. So something like:

```
INSERT INTO ASSETS(GEOMETRY, THEMES) 
    (select b.GEOMETRY.STIntersection(a.geometry, b.THEMES from 
          SITES_TEST a,
          MM_TOPO b
          where a.geometry.STBuffer(1).STIntersects(b.geometry) = 1 AND  (b.THEMES ='Land' or b.THEMES ='Roads Tracks And Paths'))
```

Comment: Hi Ian, that worked for me I just needed to remove the .stbuffer(1) element as it was causing an error "Could not find method 'stbuffer' for type 'Microsoft.SqlServerTypes.SqlGeometry' in assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types'" Thank you